# Calculating a new field depending on results in another field

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017

I'm struggling with a query. I want to increase the result of a column (decimal 8,2) by 10% or 20% depending on the another column's result e.g. team. So team a would be 10%, team b would be 20%, team c 10% etc. This field the % increase is based on is an int field.

I've tried to do this by using cast but then everything fails - and is bugging me now. Thoughts?

Here's the example of my basic table - I'm trying to practice more so I'm not totally useless in work now were expected to use SQL:

```
select 
Employee_No,
First_Name,
Last_Name,
Annual_Salary,
case d.Department_No
when '20' then Annual_Salary+5%
when '10' then Annual_Salary+5%
when '50' then Annual_Salary+10%
when '80' then Annual_Salary+10%
when '90' then Annual_Salary+10%
when '110' then Annual_salary10+%
else Annual_Salary          
end
,
Department_Name,
Department_No

from dbo.employees
```

Comment: its cut of the first bit. Should read:  Hi I'm new to SQL, and I'm struggling with a query. I want to increase the result of a column (decimal 8,2) by 10% or 20% depending on the another column's result e.g. team. So team a would be 10%, team b would be 20%, team c 10% etc. This field the % increase is based on is an int field.

I've tried to do this by using cast but then everything fails - and is bugging me now. Thoughts?

Comment: Help us help you - please [edit] your question and add the table(s) structure(s), some sample data, and the result you'd want to get for this sample

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the fraction of the salary and add it. In the `CASE` define the right factors and multiply the salaray by them.

```
SELECT employee_no,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       annual_salary,
       annual_salary
       + CASE
           WHEN department_no IN ('10', '20') THEN
             .05
           WHEN department_no IN ('50', '80', '90', '110') THEN
             .1
           ELSE
             0
         END
       * annual_salary,
       department_name,
       department_no
       FROM dbo.employees;
```

Comment: thank you ever so much! I see what you have to do now, and I'll give it a go replicating elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, this is the logic that you want:

```
select e.Employee_No, e.First_Name, e.Last_Name,e.Annual_Salary,
       (Annual_Salary *
        (case when e.Department_No in (10, 20) then 1.05
              when e.Department_No in (80, 90, 110) then 1.10
              else 1
         end)
       ) as incremented_salary
       d.Department_Name,
       d.Department_No
from dbo.employees e join
     dbo.departments d
     on d.department_no = e.department_no;
```

Notes:

- This assumes that you actually have two tables, one for employees and one for departments.  If this is not true, just remove the `join` portion.
- All column references are *qualified*, so they indicate what table they come from.
- I presume that `department_no` is a number, so I removed the single quotes around the constants.  If this is not true, then keep the single quotes.
- This simplifies the logic for the calculation.
- This can easily be turned into an `update`, if that is what you really want to accomplish.  (The question does not state that explicitly.)